# How do I complete the "Fill a business with all Skill 9 workers"?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I managed to place x3 skill 9 Bitizens in a food service job but the Emperor won't let me collect.

Does it have to be all lvl 9 and dream job?  Does it have to be something like Retail or Service, not Food?

Anyone else get stuck on this mission?

Comment: Did you already have a level 9 worker in there?  Try removing them all from that floor to unemployed and hiring them back.

Comment: Are they level 9 in the skill matching the business in question: food?

Comment: @ZeroStack Yes they all have 9 in the food column and are working at the Mos Espa Cafe.  I will try making them all unemployed and putting them back.

DoozerBlake Yes they are all 9 in food.  TY for your help guys.

Comment: @ZeroStack  Thank you!  I just had to remove the Bitizens from the business and then rehire them to pass the mission!

Comment: @Camop82 No problem!  I have made this an answer for you to accept (and upvote if you would like as well)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, if you already had the skill level 9 worker(s) on the specified floor, simply **move them to unemployed and re-hire them on that floor**.

**For this mission**:

It does not have to be their dream job for this specific mission (though there are other missions that require it to be their dream job).

It does not matter which type of floor it is as long as it is one of: Food, Service, Recreation, or Retail (AND the skill level 9 matches those floors assigned to).

Comment: Didn't work for me. I've got 3 level 9 food guys and I've moved them back and forth from one food level to another. Emperor won't sign off on it :(

Comment: There seems to be a variety of bugs at play with some of the Emperor's missions.  Perhaps you are the victim of yet another one.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this quest is by going to the **Bitizens** screen in the **Menu**. There you can view your Bitizens ordered by their skills. Click on each of the categories until you find one you have a category with at least 3 Bitizens with 9 in the highlighted column. You can then click on them and move them to a store of the corresponding category.

For example, if the category Food has 3 Bitizens with 9 on the Green column, you can click on them, remove them from their current jobs. Then you go to the *Mos Espa Cafe* and remove one of the Bitizens working there from the job, and hire the one you identified with the 9.